# How do I format a C# decimal to remove extra following 0's?

Tags: c#, format, decimal, tostring

I want to format a string as a decimal, but the decimal contains some following zeros after the decimal.  How do I format it such that those meaningless 0's disappear?

```
string.Format("{0}", 1100M);
string.Format("{0}", 1100.1M);
string.Format("{0}", 1100.100M);
string.Format("{0}", 1100.1000M);
```

displays:

```
1100
1100.1
1100.100
1100.1000
```

but I want it to be:

```
1100
1100.1
1100.1
1100.1
```

For reference, here are other questions that are essentially duplicates of this, that I've found thanks to answers given here:

- [Parse decimal and filter extra 0 on the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298719/parse-decimal-and-filter-extra-0-on-the-right)
- [Best way to display decimal without trailing zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104615/best-way-to-display-decimal-without-trailing-zeros-in-c)
- [How can I strip zeros and decimal points off of decimal strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123151/how-to-can-i-strip-zeros-and-decimal-points-off-of-decimal-strings)

Comment: Is 1002.231 Just an example? That is, would you like 1.12000 to be 1.12 or 1.120?

Comment: Note that if you want a *decimal* value, you should use one, e.g. 1100.1000m. Note the "m" for "decimal literal".

Comment: @Jon: Thanks I noticed that also and went to fix it, and your comment was waiting for me when I returned..  So fast... ;)

Comment: @n8wrl: Just an example, yes, I updated with more examples.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use `ToString()` with the [**General ("G") Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString) to achieve the desired result. Trailing zeros are truncated when using this format string with a precision specified. In order to prevent rounding in any situations, you will need to set the precision to the maximum allowed for decimals (29).

The line of code to produce what you want is `number.ToString("G29")`, where `number` is your original decimal.

Be aware that any numbers smaller than 0.0001 will be converted to scientific notation. More details on how this formatter works can be found at the reference link above.

Comment: I think this is the best solution to the question.

Comment: Concur -- switched answer.  Thanks, @Herohtar.

Comment: WARNING: Watch out for values like 0.000001. G29 format will present them in the shortest possible way so it will switch to the exponential notation. string.Format("{0:G29}", decimal.Parse("0.00000001",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-U‌​S"))) will give "1E-08" as the result.
Credit goes to Konrad here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525854/remove-trailing-zeros/4525983#4525983

Comment: @DougS: It seems that it switches to scientific notation for numbers less than 0.0001 (eg, 0.0001 remains the same, but 0.00009 will be 9E-05) That seems unlikely to be a problem in most cases of wanting to truncate zeros, but a good thing to know nonetheless.

Comment: @Herohtar: I wouldn't say it's "unlikely" at all. In fact, it's very likely if someone is working with decimals less than 1. For instance, I store decimal(12,10) in my database, and G29 would fail on 0.0000010000 or anything like it.

Comment: The answer has been updated with a correct link and current information.

Comment: I still get the trailing zeros with the "G" formatting.

Comment: The G29 is not necessary. "G0"=="G29" for decimal

Comment: What if I don't want it to use scientific notation?

Answer (score 23):

```
string s = d.ToString("0.#############################");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
String.Format("{0:0.000}", x);
```

Comment: But I don't know that it's got three decimals on the end, I meant that only as an example.  I'll make the question clearer.

Answer (score 4):

They're not necessarily meaningless - they indicate the precision during calculation. Decimals maintain their precision level, rather than being normalized.

I have some code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298719/parse-decimal-and-filter-extra-0-on-the-right) which will return a normalized value - you could use that, and then format the result. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

class Test
{
    static void Display(decimal d)
    {
        d = d.Normalize(); // Using extension method from other post
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Display(123.4567890000m); // Prints 123.456789
        Display(123.100m);        // Prints 123.1
        Display(123.000m);        // Prints 123
        Display(123.4567891234m); // Prints 123.4567891234
    }
}
```

I *suspect* that most of the format string approaches will fail. I would guess that a format string of "0." and then 28 # characters would work, but it would be very ugly...

Comment: It looks like your solution is for .Net 4.0 only.

Comment: @Gabe: Unless you use a 3rd party BigInteger implementation, yes. It's also pretty inefficient. On the other hand, it has the advantage of working :)

Answer (score 4):

Unlike what everybody suggest to use a `G` format specifier I would suggest the following to preserve both thousand separator and decimal point while removing extra trailing zeros:

```
{0:#,#.##}
```

The result of this format is much better than G in most cases:

```
String.Format("{0:#,#.##}",25/2.4);
10.42

String.Format("{0:#,#.##}",1000000);
1,000,000

String.Format("{0:#,#.##}",1000000.3600000);
1,000,000.36
```

And the `G` specifier can't really handle all the possible combinations:

```
String.Format("{0:G29}",25/2.4);
10.416666666666668

String.Format("{0:G2}",25/2.4);
10

String.Format("{0:G29}",1000000.3600000);
1000000.36

String.Format("{0:G2}",1000000.3600000);
1E+06
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
string FormatDecimal(decimal d)
{
    const char point = System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator[0];
    string s = d.ToString();
    // if there's no decimal point, there's nothing to trim
    if (!s.Contains(point) == -1)
        return s;
    // trim any trailing 0s, followed by the decimal point if necessary
    return s.TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd(point);
}
```

Comment: Use System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator instead of '.'?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few answers already. I often refer to this cheat sheet: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat hackish, but this should work:

```
decimal a = 100.00M;
string strNumber = string.Format("{0}", a);
Console.WriteLine(strNumber.Contains('.') ? strNumber.TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.') : strNumber);
```

Comment: Ack! What if `a = 100.000`? Or `a = 0`?

Comment: @Gabe Was in the process of fixing

Comment: @kerk should be fixed now.  Let me know if you find any counterexamples to the updated answer.

Comment: Wouldn't mind a downvote removal unless the updated answer still isn't satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0); // "123"
```

Comment: Should be... String.Format("{0:0.0##}", 123.456789m) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to do:

```
var s = String.Format("{0:#####.###}");
```

Answer (score -3):

```
double a = 1100.00
double  b =1100.1
double  c = 1100.100
double  d =1100.1000

Remove last zero after point


string stra = a.toString("0.00").TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.');
string strb = b.toString("0.00").TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.');
string strc = c.toString("0.00").TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.');
string strd = d.toString("0.00").TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.');

Output

1100
1100.1
1100.1
1100.1
```